# c# need help by moving a object in two direction

Tags: c#

I need help by moving a object on a Panel in two different direction. In example in the right and down direction by pressing the right and left buttons. Java have a a key release method do c# have such a similiar method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace runningRectangle
{
  enum Position {Left, Right, Down, Up, LeftUp, LeftDown, RightUp, RightDown }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int x;
        private int y; 
        private Position objPos;
        private int speed = 10;
        private bool stopPressed = false;

    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
        x = 50;
        y = 50;


    }

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(objPos == Position.Right)
        {
            x += speed;

        }else if(objPos == Position.Left)
        {
            x -= speed;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.Down)
        {
            y += speed;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.Up)
        {
            y -= speed;
        } else if (objPos == Position.RightUp)
        {
            x += speed;
            y -= speed;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.RightDown)
        {
            x += speed;
            y += speed;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.LeftUp)
        {
            x -= speed;
            y += speed;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.LeftDown)
        {
            x -= speed;
            y -= speed;
        }

        Invalidate();
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
            objPos = Position.Right;

            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
            objPos = Position.Left;

        }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
            objPos = Position.Down;

        }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
            objPos = Position.Up;
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            objPos = Position.RightDown; 
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            objPos = Position.RightUp;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            objPos = Position.LeftDown;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            objPos = Position.LeftUp;

        }

        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            if (!stopPressed)
            {
                speed = 0;
                stopPressed = true;
            }
            else if(stopPressed)
            {
                speed += 10;
                stopPressed = false;
            }
        }        
        }
}
}
```

Comment: C# has [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

`Form1_KeyDown` and `Form1_KeyUp` exist in pair.

```
enum Position { None = -1, Left, Right, Down, Up, LeftUp, LeftDown, RightUp, RightDown }

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    objPos = (Position)(-1);
}
```